# draw an image on a widget with Qt

Tags: c++, qt

I'm discovering Qt and I'm stuck on a very simple problem: I try to draw an image on a widget.

I have no issue at drawing some Pies or Rectangles, but I see nothing for the image...

Here is the part of may code:

```
void GraphicWidget::paintEvent(QPaintEvent * /* event */)
{
QPainter painter(this);
painter.setPen(Qt::red);
painter.setBrush(Qt::blue);
painter.translate(0, rect().height());

QPixmap pixmap;
if ( pixmap.load("Lena.png") )
{
     std::cout << "succes" << std::endl;
     painter.drawPixmap( QPoint(100,100), pixmap );
}
else
     std::cout << "fail" << std::endl;

    painter.drawPie(QRect(-35, -35, 70, 70), 0, 90 * 16);//works
    painter.drawRect(QRect(30, -5, 20, 10));            //works
}
```

Comment: So you can't _load_ image?

Comment: I thin I can load it, since I use the same image as an icon for the mainWindow, and I print "succes" when I reach this "load line"

Comment: Is your program printing "success" or "fail"? If "fail" then try to specify full path to the png file or place that file into the working directory of your executable. Note also that in most cases you shouldn't reimplement paintevent in Qt. Use QGraphicsScene instead.

Comment: May be `QPoint(100,100)` is just out of scene?

Comment: Also, why don't you just use `QLabel`? It can show pixmaps.

Comment: Probably he wants to do more than just drawing that single pixmap.

Comment: yes, the program prints "success". The issue was simply that I was out of scene. Thank for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have translated the coordination system of QPainter. So your `x` should be in [0, width] interval and your `y` should be in [-height, 0] interval. `QPoint(100,100)` is out of your widget's borders.